# Dangling modifier in Style Guide?

Tags: grammar, modifiers

> When writing English, Strunk & White apply.

Am I the only one who sees a dangling modifier here?

It may be borderline, but how close to the border?

In "strict mode", my ears hear:

> When they write English, Strunk & White apply.

What do you hear?

This would sound clearer to me:

> When writing English, follow Strunk & White.

If the thang does dangle, it's a tad embarrassing because it features in a [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). How to give an admonishment and break it at the same time...

Comment: I cannot actually tell what your question is here.

Comment: I'm no great fan of Strunk & White at the best of times, and this could perhaps be a US/UK difference, but *"Strunk & White **applies**"* seems better to me. After all, it's *"Strunk & White **is** a style guide"*, not *"Strunk & White **are** a style guide"*.

Comment: It is a dangling modifier alright, and it is also true that Strunk and White don't like dangling modifiers. However, Strunk and White cannot comprehend or follow their own advice on a great many accounts and occasions, so this sentence is, at worst, perfectly in line with Strunk and White, and at best, actually a clever stab at their ineptitude.

Comment: @tchrist: In *follow Strunk & White*, the implied "subject" for *writing* is a deleted ***you*** - which gets around the "dangling modifier" issue. The question is whether the lack of a credible implied subject in OP's first example makes it an "ungrammatical" example of a dangling modifier.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can see the theoretical point you're making, but  the prescription reads like an out-and-out instruction, not an instance of an elided pronoun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers `I'm no great fan of Strunk & White` Neither I am. Who are you a fan of? Joseph Williams is my boy.

Comment: @Erik: 1: *When posting on ELU, avoid using dangling modifiers.* That's an imperative/instruction with an elided subject "you". 2: *When posting on ELU, dangling modifiers should be avoided.* That's an *instruction*, but I don't know if it can properly be called an *imperative* form, and I'm not sure it's really a valid example of a dangling modifier itself. But I would certainly take issue with anyone who tried to tell me #2 was "ungrammatical".

Comment: @zx81: On the *language* front, presumably we all have to bow before James McCawley - though for a "good read", Steven Pinker is my boy, and if we're limited to ELU users John Lawler will always get my vote. But if we're allowed to include *musicians/lyricists*, I really admire Loudon Wainwright's use of language. Until now I'd never even *heard* of Joseph Williams, and you'll be disappointed to know that in my 50,000-track music library the *only* Toto song is their cover of *Watching the Detectives* (which I never got around to deleting when I finally got hold of the *right* version! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for sharing all these names, many unknown to me. That will give me something to do. By Joseph Williams, I meant the author of [Style: Toward Clarity and Grace](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0226899152/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Books by James McCawley: which is your top pick? Thanks. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers From Pinker, I loved `How the Mind Works` and `The Blank Slate` but haven't read anything of his lately. Will look up the others. Sorry for raining comments on you.

Comment: @zx81: oic. At my age, I'm not really interested in consulting style guides to "improve" my use of English. If there are any "rules" I haven't picked up on already then frankly I think they're probably either pedantic/marginal or mistaken/outdated. I couldn't care less (or being more "modern/American", I *could* care less) about whether using a style guide would cause me to make *fewer* mistakes or *less* mistakes in the eyes of pedants.

Comment: The definitive McCawley is [The Syntactic Phenomena of English](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Syntactic-Phenomena-English-James-Mccawley/dp/0226556298) - but be warned it will cost you an arm and a leg (that's for the *paperback* edition - the hardback one will also require a mortgage, the shirt off your back, and a pact with the Devil! :)

Comment: When writing English, McCawley's _Syntactic Phenomena of English_ apply.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your advice... Yes, I'll have to find a pretty penny somewhere. :) At my age... ditto. But that's not what the Williams is about. It has an extraordinarily lucid way of explaining what makes so much writing turgid. The section on `nominalizations` (among others) is priceless. It's a gem. I often recommend it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it was B. Bryson who said that to know English is to know when one may actually use DM. However, I try to avoid them at all times, and I think *"When writing English, follow Strunk & White."* sounds way better than *"When writing English, Strunk & White apply."*, which seems sort of clumsy. Anyway, I'm not a native speaker so...

Comment: *You* may not be a native speaker - but I am, and I think everything you say here is spot-on.

Comment: "When writing English, Strunk & White apply" sounds like early Yoda.